# Unclear Code Sniffer Errors

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I have followed html markup with php code:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php if ($user->isOnline()): ?>
            <a href="<?=Url::create('/user/logout');?>">Logout</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run code sniffer, I get following errors:

```
<error line="3" column="15" severity="error" message="Line indented incorrectly; expected 8 spaces, found 0" source="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent.Incorrect"/>
<error line="5" column="15" severity="error" message="Closing brace must be on a line by itself" source="PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.Line"/>
```

I've tried to find any standards or descriptions about php constructions in html views, but nothing about it's.

Maybe, anybody knows how should looks `if` and `foreach` instructions in html?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove one indentation of your `<a href...` line.

Comment: @VincentDecaux, no, it's not working.

Comment: You might want to try upgrading to the latest PHPCS version if you aren't on 2.3.4 because there have been fixes added for this sort of view code, assuming you are using a built-in standard like PSR2 or PEAR.

Comment: @GregSherwood, thanks, but unfortunately, I can't upgrade current version of code sniffer to latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, but code looks not pretty good:

```
<div class="block">
<div class="block-title">
    <?php
    if ($user->isOnline()): ?>
        <a href="<?=Url::create('/user/logout');?>">Logout</a>
    <?php
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

So I decided to add views files to Code Sniffer ignore list with `@codingStandardsIgnoreFile` annotation. Now, need to manually check code style, but code looks much better.